# Keeping List View and View Pager in sync

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

Forgive me if the title is a little vague, I'm having trouble wording this issue, which is also why I am unable to find any examples via Google.

I'm using the master/detail flow layout in my application as I mostly develop on a tablet.
[image: Master/Detail Flow:]

The implementation follows the usual pattern, two Fragments being contained in one Activity and I have it working perfectly. In this case the detail is actually a `ViewPager`, with the `ViewPager` and the `ListView` being alternate forms of displaying the same data.

So selecting an item in the list will scroll the `ViewPager` to the position and swiping across will update the selected item in the list.

Here's what I have so far:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements VideoListFragment.Callbacks, VideoDetailFragment.Callbacks {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String callingClass, int id) {

        //Work out which one we're updating based on which class called this method
        if (callingClass == VideoListFragment.VIDEO_LIST_ID) {
            //Update the VideoDetail
            VideoDetailFragment fragment = (VideoDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane);
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setViewPagerPosition(id);
            } else {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putInt(VideoDetailFragment.VIDEO_ID, id);
                fragment = new VideoDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_pane, fragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        } else if (callingClass == VideoDetailFragment.VIDEO_DETAIL_ID) {
            //Update the VideoList
            VideoListFragment fragment = (VideoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_pane);
            fragment.setSelection(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**ListFragment.java**

```
public class ListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onItemSelected(String callingClass, int id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        setSelection(position);
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(VIDEO_LIST_ID, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

**VideoDetailFragment.java**

```
    public class VideoDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onItemSelected(String callingClass, int id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Left
        if (mListPosition > position + positionOffset) {
            mCallbacks.onItemSelected(VIDEO_DETAIL_ID, position);
        } else //Right
        {
            mCallbacks.onItemSelected(VIDEO_DETAIL_ID, position);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a pretty basic system but it works for the most part, the only problem is that the system often calls `onPageScrolled` when the views are being refreshed, such as when new data has downloaded and `notifyDatasetChanged` is called. This leads to a lot of to and fro-ing with the listview selection flying up and down and looks tacky overall.

A good example of what I want is the GMail app, it has the master detail flow and updates seamlessly. Is there any code examples of this anywhere?

Thanks in advance.